# How to Optimize a Large Number of BoxColliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am implementing a Terraria-like level generation using Perlin noise.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdFwN.jpg)

Now I managed to procedurally arrange the blocks on the map and divide them into chunks of 32x32 blocks. I made it so that the chunks that the player does not see are disabled (SetActive false) and now the question arises to add a collider / colliders for these blocks.

I tried to just assign one collider per block, but when the chunk is loaded, the fps drops to very low values. I also tried to just make one big composite collider for each chunk, but then the ability to select blocks with the mouse and break them disappears, but this is the basic mechanic of my game. Any help is welcome

PS Sorry for my bad England

Comment: I would try activate/deactivate the colliders base on need. Don't know your case but can be based on distance to player or to the cursor, so that only the colliders that are going to be potentially affected are listening to collision events.

Comment: Did you tried to use composite colliders ? Like, one composite collider by chunk.
Do you have the fps drop ? I know, that if you use this, it's not straightforward to detect what block is collided, but you can use your chunk as database to get what cube is collided (with the position of the contact)